# algebraic surface singling out an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, surfaces

$\newcommand\P{\mathbb P}$I read the following classic result which does not give a proof but refers to a very old Italian work (Gallarati) that I cannot get hold of (and even if I do, probably I wouldn't understand it as it is in Italian):

> Suppose that $X$ is an irreducible surface nonsingular in codimension 1 in $\P^3$
> and $Y,Y'\ne X$ are surfaces in $\P^3$ such that
> $$X\cap Y = C_1\cup \dots \cup C_k$$
> and $X\cap Y' = C_1$
> , where $C_i$ are irreducible curves.
> Then there exists another surface $Z$
> such that $$X\cap Z = C_2 \cup \dots \cup C_k$$

By curve, surface etc. I mean in the context of algebraic geometry i.e. algebraic and over an algebraically closed field. Maybe this is trivial in modern algebraic geometry but I cannot see the proof. In fact I am more interested in the construction of $Z$ rather than the proof. Can anyone assist me in constructing $Z$ or at least give a proof of this (or maybe cite a reference that is accessible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality gives a linear equivalence
$$
dH \sim n_1C_1 + n_2C_2 + \dots + n_kC_k
$$
of Weil divisors on $X$, where $H$ is the hyperplane class, $d$ is the degree of $Y$, and $n_i$ are some positive integers. Similarly, the second equality means
$$
d'H \sim n'C_1.
$$
Therefore
$$
(n'd - d'n_1)H \sim n'n_2C_2 + \dots + n'n_kC_k.
$$
The right side is effective, hence $n'd - d'n_1 > 0$. Since $X$ is a hypersurface, the linear system $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(n'd - d'n_1)$ cuts the complete linear system $|(n'd - d'n_1)H|$ on $X$, which implies the existence of a surface $Z$ as required.

Comment: Ok. At least I understand the degree of a candidate $Z$ and why in fact $Z$ exists. Do you know how I could algorithmically find the polynomial defining $Z$? Should I do some linear algebra on the coefficients of the monomials of polynomial of degreee $n'd-d'n_1$ to find this polynomial?

Comment: Just take $F^{d'}/(F')^{n_1}$, where $F$ and $F'$ are the equations of $Y$ and $Y'$.